# How to find more suitable drivers?

Tags: drivers, sound, hp, gpu-driver, ubuntu-drivers

I am new to Ubuntu and I've installed it on my laptop 3 days ago. I have HP 15 notebook PC laptop and the Ubuntu version I am using is 16.04 LTS. I have some problems I can't solve and I believe it is because of the drivers. For example my sound volume is very low even at 100% and my laptops heats up a lot faster than when it was working with Windows. My question is does anyone knows where and how to find more suitable drivers?

Comment: HP laptops are notorious for running hot, I know, I have a DV7.  Do you have the dual hybrid AMD/Intel graphics?  16.04 causes issues with this because both graphic cards stay powered all the time.  And the AMD card creates heat for nothing because it's not even being used.

Answer (score 1):

We have 2 types of drivers:

1. Generic
2. 3rd party

The generic drivers are used to install your system and generally are enough to get daily tasks done.

For high graphics usage,  gaming, you probably need the 3rd party driver.

All 3rd party drivers that have been tested and are deemed working are installable from the 'additional drivers' option.

If you then still have issues I'd advice to start looking at the logs and look for errors. Other drivers are probably not what you need. Or .... there are likely no better drivers other than you already can install.

Also: AMD is working on new drivers for linux. Users with an AMD card are advised to stick with 14.04. If yours is an AMD, consider downgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Type " Additional Drivers " in " Dash ". You will get a multi tabbed window where you can check for " Additional Drivers " or proprietary drivers.

I am not sure if it is really a driver issue. If the driver is not working, you might be having no sound at all. Also, laptop's heating issue may not be due to Ubuntu.

Will it be possible for you to try those audio files on another PC ?

Answer (score 0):

The new AMD GPU drivers for Linux have been released this past weekend, i would highly advise upgrading to them... My desktop system, AMD 8 core-8350fx with a Radeon R9 380x runs far quieter, smoother and cooler, and getting frame rates about on par with the same game (Bioshock Infinite as a benchmark on ultra settings @ 1080p)